# gmsk: suppression of higher-frequency spectral components

Tags: digital-communications, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density, gmsk

I study gmsk modulation and worked with gmsk implementation, BT = 0.5. I have decided to test with BT = 0.25, which is used for near Earth communicaiton.

**Spectrum of output signal with BT  = 0.5, oversampling ratio 4 and truncated length of the filter 3**

[image]

I used the same simulation and plotted for  **BT  = 0.25, oversampling ratio 4 and truncated length of the filter 3**

[image]

Obviously, the -70dB suppression of higher-frequency spectral components is achieved at BT=0.5 (the first figure), but not at BT=0.25 (the second plot).

What can I change if I want -70dB for BT = 0.25?

**EDIT 1**
new spectrum for BT = 0.25. Matlab code is below ( edit 2)

[image]

Comment: (ignoring any domain-specific background knowledge, we can ask ourselves:) You have three parameters, one of which is just an interpolation factor, and one you explicitly fix. Can you address your concern by varying the remaining one? If that's not possible, then your requirement is impossible. If it's possible, you found your solution.

Comment: (suddenly re-discovering our domain knowledge:) 3 is a ridiculously short length for a filter than needs to achieve a suppression of 70 dB (which is very much, and unusually high in most practical applications). You see that in your top graph very well. Does that look more like a bell curve, or more like |sinc|?

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you for your comments. I will "play" with my simulation. The first one looks more like abs(sinc), the second one looks more like a bell

Comment: and you know why, right? (this doesn't ask for experimentation, honestly, this requires you to think about *why* you're truncating, and what happens when you do that. It did not randomly fall from the sky that I said |sinc|.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller FrHart64 how do you determine the suppression? is it the level of sidelibes? which part of the spectrum gives you it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller as I uderstand, sinc we get becouse of convolution the gaussian pulse with a rectangular pulse, right? gaussian pulse is formed like bell shaped function...

Comment: @MarcusMüller gaussian function is -inf +inf, nad we truncated it and it help to resuce sidelobes, right?

Comment: @FrHart64 exactly, truncation = multiplication with a rectangular window = *circular* convolution with a sinc in the discrete frequency domain.

Comment: @FrHart64 no, truncating only makes your filter *worse*, not better in anything but length.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you wrote, suppression in 70db is high, but for BT 0.5 we can reach it

Comment: @FrHart64 you did not reach it for a BT=0.5 Gaussian filter, at all. You reached it for a sinc-filter with slightly Gaussian window. As you said yourself, your first filter is not Gaussian at all after truncation. You broke it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I thought I should change smth and I will able to reach such suppression :(

Comment: @MarcusMüller i plotted the spectrum of the baseband signal ( outputof gmsk modulator) .... at least it is less than -60 dB  . I am confused now:(

Comment: it is below -60 dB, but it's not Gaussian. You need Gaussian AND -60 dB, not only one.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, the new plot( edit 1), does it look correct, right?

Comment: it doesn't look very Gaussian to me.